# Jenkins <> Allure - 404 or NaN on test-results

Tags: jenkins, allure

I tried setting up Allure Report with Jenkins, but every time the build is finished and I click on the report, it's opening a 404 page or NaN empty report page.

Attached are my configurations and below is stack trace:

```
[SeleniumJob] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation/allure/bin/allure generate -c -o /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SeleniumJob/allure-report
allure-results does not exist
Report successfully generated to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SeleniumJob/allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Finished: FAILURE
```

It seems allure-results does not exist but I can't find out why because I see it in the Jenkins workspace

This is how the link looks like once clicked on Allure in Jenkins: https://3.236.42.121/job/SeleniumJob/4/allure/

Thank you for your help!

[image: workspace]

[image: job configuration]